# Two threads, same version number but no StaleObject Exception

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a scenario where two actions updates a Domain object. Sometimes based on the timing, both the actions gets called at the same time(almost) and the domain object they fetch contains the same version number. Now one of the action will update the domain object first and when the other action updates it there should be an error as the action first updating the object must increment the version number so it should throw staleObjectException. But in my case the object is successfully updated with no exception being thrown. Just curious to know why ?

Following is the scenario reproduced(sometimes based on the click timing)

```
    // Gets called at a regular interval via ajax call

    updateTime(){
    DomainA obj = DomainA.get(id)
    println obj.version // prints 5
    obj.setSomeProperty(value)
    obj.save(failOnError:true)
    }

    // Gets called on a click of a button(Normal request)

    pause(){
    DomainA obj = DomainA.get(sameid)
    println obj.version // prints 5
    obj.setSomeProperty(value)
    obj.save(failOnError:true)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the hibernate SQL logging and the update statements?

Comment: you run the update into services right ? not controller

Comment: @Henri. In the controller. I call obj.save(failOnError:true)

Comment: so first, move your code in a services, spring will handle the transaction part for you and you should be safe

Comment: @Henri I am already safe as no exception is thrown but wondering why?

Comment: I mean safe from transaction side, when you create grails services, they are automatically registered as spring beans and by default they are singleton (that can be changed) and are transactional by default

Comment: The exception your expecting won't occur until the transaction is flushed. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#locking. Try calling the save method like this: obj.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa But when the transaction ends all the database changes would be committed. Right ? So it should throw exception when the transaction ends. I think by default controller's actions are transnational. One of the action would update the row first and the other action should throw StaleObject Exception. Please let me know if I am incorrect.

Comment: By default services are transactional but controllers are not.